# Strange issue with ruby lirbary for Kaltura

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaltura

I'm trying to integrate Kaltura video's in my Rails project, for which I use the ruby library from Kaltura. I'm running into the problem that my code works fine on console and the exact same code running under rails server causes a nasty crash (or freeze actually, no debug, I have to kill the process manually to be able to restart).

So my questions:

- could there be a difference in libraries that both instances are
  running? I'm pretty new to the gem stuff, so I don't know if this
  could even be possible.
- Is there a way to verify (by using a command or such) to check that
  both are accessing the same library?
- What could be causing such nasty freezes on server without also causing that on the console

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: how are you starting the console vs how are you starting the rails app? (full command) what does your environment look like?

Comment: `rails s` versis `rails c`, nothing special. My environment as in system? I'm testing locally on a Macbook.

Comment: you environment as in system, rbenv/rvm and actual env vars

Comment: I found out the problem was 'caused' by byebug... The normal code does run like it should. Still strange, but more acceptable. Thanks for your help.